# activeadmin breadcrumb with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

describe the structure:
- Projects(all projects)
-- Project 1(all KPI of Project 1)
--- KPI 1(all Tasks of KPI 1)
---- Task 1
---- Task 3
--- KPI 2
-- Project 2

please tell me how can I solve this problem.

I need that would be when an administrator is in the problem, he could go on the bread crumbs on a page with a list of tasks, but also to the parameters passed to it before choosing the filter from sidebar.

Is it possible?

**From rus**
мне нужно, что бы когда администратор находится в задаче, он мог по хлебным крошкам перейти на страницу со списком задач, но в адрес так же передавались параметры, которые он до этого выбирал в фильтре сайтбара. Возможно ли это?